# Python: how to find a range of indexes from small to large?

Tags: python, arrays, list, output

I have 2 arrays. First is an array of rows. Second is an array of indents (think indenting text in a Word document)

1.
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']

2.
['1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '1', '2']

I am struggling with finding a range of variables from a small number to the next bigger one.

My desired output would be

1. '1', '2', '3'
2. '1', '2', '3'

also,

1. '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'
2. '1', '2', '2', '2', '2'

I want to save the indexes of the of the array that stops when the next number is smaller than the previous.

Such as arraySaved = [['1', '3'],['4', '8']['9', '10']]

I keep getting 'out of index errors' and the saved indexes are not reflecting the correct range

Code I've tried:

```
num = 0 
arrayOfIndexes = []
for x in range(0, len(array1)):
    small= array2[int(num)]
    num = int(num)+1
    big = array2[int(num)]

    if(big - num <=0): 
       arrayOfIndexes.append(num)
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Why isn't `'9', '10'` `'1', '2'` included in the output?

Comment: "I am struggling with finding a range of variables from a small number to the next bigger one." is really ambiguous. From what I understand, you want to slice both list_1 and list_2 based on when the next value in list_2 is less than the previous? (Note, they're all strings in your example, not integers). You could do this quite logically with `for` loops for a start, please show what you have tried.

Comment: Does the first list actually influence anything?

Comment: @MooingRawr
okay, added some code

Comment: @Aran-Fey I just wanted a system to work with one set that can be applied throughout the array

Comment: @ArndtJonasson yeah, I am trying to make bullet pointed 'notes,' each with their own indent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this accomplishes what you want, if I interpreted your question correctly:

```
indents = ['1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '1', '2']

arraySaved = []; temp = [0] #Initialize temporary list
for idx, i in enumerate(indents):
    if idx==len(indents)-1:
        temp.append(idx)
        arraySaved.append(temp) #Reached end of list
    elif indents[idx+1]<i: #Ending index of temporary list
        temp.append(idx)
        arraySaved.append(temp) #Store temporary list
        temp = []; temp.append(idx+1) #Reset temporary list and begin new one

print(arraySaved)
```

Yields:

```
[[0, 2], [3, 7], [8, 9]]
```

Keep in mind that your desired output is the upper and lower bounds of the row indices after being separated into individually increasing indent counts. Therefore, you do not actually need the list `rows`, since you can just enumerate the list `indents`. The answer above is equivalent to your desired output if you keep in mind that Python indexes from 0, not 1.

Figured I would add that if you **really** want the row numbers indexed from 1, then you can do the following:

```
arraySaved = [[i+1 for i in j] for j in arraySaved]
```

Gives:

```
[[2, 3], [4, 8], [9, 10]]
```

**Explanation**

`temp` is simply a list used to temporarily store the indices of the values in `indents` that correspond to the starting and ending indices for each individual outputted list eventually stored in `arraySaved`. We need to initialize `temp` as well with the first index of the list, i.e. `0`.

`for idx, i in enumerate(indents):` simply loops through the values inside of the list `indents`, where `enumerate` also unpacks the indices of the values inside of the list as well

The first `if` statement accounts for the case that the current index in the loop is the last one in the list, because then `idx+1` would exceed the dimensions of the list being iterated on. If either of the criteria in the `if` statements are satisfied, then the current index is stored in the `temp` variable. If the ending index criteria is satisfied then the `temp` list is reset after being appended to `arraySaved`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Wow! Thank you. That worked great. Awesome. Could you link me to a tutorial explaining your answer?

Comment: There is no formal tutorial for my answer, so I provided an explanation above. If you feel that this answered your question, please click the green check mark to accept my answer!